# IDMPhotoBrowser doesn't load image from AWSS3 bucket

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, afnetworking

I am working on integrating IDMPhotoBrowser into my app that uses an AWSS3 bucket. If I enter the link into my browser, it properly downloads the image. If I pass the link through an AWSS3TransferManager it also works. It even works when I use SDWebImage and specify the url.

For some reason however, when I put the url into IDMPhotoBrowser, it will not load. I have tested it with other images not located in the bucket and they will load fine. I also have checked that the bucket is set to public, as are its objects.

I am about to attempt to use the MWPhotoBrowser since it uses SDWebImage. If anyone has any other suggestions please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to determine why, but I found that AFNetworking as currently set up through IDMPhotoBrowser does not work with AWSS3.

There are two solutions. One was to use MWPhotoBrowser, which I implemented. The second was that there is a branch of IDMPhotoBrowser that another user has edited to use SDWebImage instead of AFNetworking. That repository can be found here: https://github.com/mythodeia/IDMPhotoBrowser

Hope this helps anyone else stuck on this problem even though I couldn't really solve it...only work around it.